# Excel VBA Loops with values belonging to a set

Tags: loops, excel, vba

Does Excel VBA allow looping for index values belonging to some given set?

For example, is can we do something like

```
Sub testloop()
  k = 1    

  For j in {30042, 2300023, 1003044}

      Range("A" & k).Select
       With Selection.Interior

          .Color = j

      End With
    k = k + 1
  Next j

End Sub
```

Right now I am using Arrays to accomplish the same

```
Sub testloop()

    Dim IndexArray(3) As Variant

    For k = 1 To 3

         IndexArray(k) = Int((10000000 - 39000 + 1) * Rnd + 39000)

    Next k


    For j = 1 To UBound(IndexArray)
        Range("A" & j).Select
         With Selection.Interior

            .Color = IndexArray(j)

        End With
    Next j

End Sub
```

So this produces colors in cells A1, A2, and A3 based on the random integer values stored in the set IndexArray. Is there a better way to loop to some set of Index values rather than storing them in Arrays?

**EDIT**

Following Simoco's solution, I did this:

```
Sub testloop()

    Dim IndexArray(2) As Variant

    For k = 0 To 2

        IndexArray(k) = Int((10000000 - 39000 + 1) * Rnd + 39000)

    Next k

    kk = 70

    For j = 0 To UBound(IndexArray)

         Range("A" & kk).Select
         With Selection.Interior

               .Color = IndexArray(j)

         End With
         kk = kk + 1
    Next j


     For Each j In IndexArray

          Range("A" & kk).Select
          With Selection.Interior

               .Color = j

          End With
          kk = kk + 1
      Next j

End Sub
```

and it works perfectly!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Sub testloop()
   k = 1

   For Each j In Array(30042, 2300023, 1003044)
       Range("A" & k).Select
       With Selection.Interior
         .Color = j
       End With
       k = k + 1
   Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please see my edit and maybe help me see why I am getting the extra black color in the second loop.

Comment: Actually there is 4 elements in your array. When you declare `Dim IndexArray(3) As Variant`, you get an array with dimension from 0 to 3, and you haven't define `IndexArray(0)`, so it's equals to 0 by default.

Comment: Oh thanks...so if I had a large Array set and I did not want to list all of them:  IndexArray(.......very long...), can I do:  For each j In IndexArray except j = 0 ? Oh ok.. Just define my index from 0 to 2. OK got it.

Comment: You can just declare `Dim IndexArray(1 To 3) As Variant` and you will get equal solutions for both methods your and mine (because your `IndexArray` will be with dimension from 1 to 3 now).